# MitM Attack Fails on Home Wireless Router

Tags: man-in-the-middle, arp-spoofing, ettercap, bettercap

I am currently trying to perform a MitM attack on my home wireless network to get a better understanding on how this attack works. I can successfully perform this attack on a NAT network on some virtual machines but it will not work on my home wireless network with an external WiFi adapter. More specifically, the target devices are not able to load webpages even while still connected to the WiFi. However, I can still view the packets sent from the device to the gateway.

I have used Bettercap, Ettercap and arpspoof to try and accomplish this and it all fails with the same result. I'm positive that the target IP and the gateway is specified for each tool and I made sure that I enabled portforwarding with `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`.

My only logical conclusion is that it is somehow not successfully redirecting the packets from the target machine to the gateway and vice versa.

Is anyone able to suggest any fixes? Are some routers able to prevent MitM attacks? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

(I am using an Alfa AC1200 wireless adapter and running Kali on a VM. I also have a Bell HomeHub 3000 which is from what I believe exclusive to Canada and manufactured by Sagecom.)

Edit:

Bettercap

`bettercap -iface wlan0
net.probe on
set arp.spoof.targets 192.168.2.28
set arp.spoof.fullduplex true
arp.spoof on
set net.sniff.local true
net.sniff on`

Arpspoof

`arpspoof -i wlan0 -t 192.168.2.28 -r 192.168.2.1`

Comment: More information about the commands you are running is probably needed.

Comment: @multithr3at3d I've been trying to use Bettercap. The commands I use are in the post.